# Drupal: storing images and other module data

Tags: image, drupal

Suppose we have a module that displays tables of employees. Each employee has a photo. What is the best way to store this photos and display them?

I mean, is there some kind of content repository in drupal? I don't want to do this manually, maybe there is an API that can store images and then generate links to them and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Content Construction Kit(CCK)](http://drupal.org/project/cck) / Fields in core is what you want to explore.

Using CCK you can attach an image, a number field, a file, some text, a reference to content, etc to another piece of content.

In Drupal 7 you can add fields to any entity (Content, User...your custom one(Employee)), in Drupal 6 you might want to explore [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile)

Further Reading:

http://drupal.org/node/717120

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of content repository in Drupal: both in the database and as storage (disk).

The API for that is documented in a special [File upload section](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/group/file/6).

If you want inspiration, the core module called `upload.module` can serve as example. But be aware that Drupal core, for several reasons, is far from the best and cleanest examples to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is CCK module with [file-field](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) and [image-field](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) modules for handling the image upload action.

And for the display of those uploaded images you should use [Image-cache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache)